# How to Cookie Sharing 2 different apps

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

There are 2 separate applications written with ASp.net core. They use the same port. When the user login in 1 application, I want to be able to login in the other application. How can I do that? Is it possible with cookie sharing?

I tried ASP.NET Core - Cookie Sharing Authentication. But I couldn't adapt it to my own application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share your cookie configuration how did you tired that, are you getting any  error while trying to manipulate the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are 2 separate applications written with ASp.net core. They use
> the same port. When the user login in 1 application, I want to be able
> to login in the other application. How can I do that? Is it possible
> with cookie sharing?

Based on your scenario and description, it appeared that, you want to use same cookie among the different apps.

Yes in asp.net core you can implement that by using either [Share cookies across different base paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#share-cookies-across-different-base-paths) or within [sub-domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#share-cookies-across-subdomains)

Each type of cookie settings has its own configuration. It would be very nicer if you could shared your code snippet in details, how did you tried to set the cookie among your application.

However, you can do as following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Your Cookie Key Path"))
    .SetApplicationName("YourAppName");

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```

**Note:** Depending on the type of cookie you would like to set within your apps, [please refer to the official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)